# Why is it necessary to enter the object twice for a class?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am just getting started with linked lists, and I wrote some basic functions with a linked list class and node objects. When calling a function, it seems that I have to enter in the linked list object twice and I think I'm doing something wrong. To add a new node with value "b" to the tail, I have to call
sample_list.add_tail_node(sample_list, "b"), when I think it is supposed to be sample_list.add_tail_node("b"), because what is the point of specifying sample_list twice

```
class LinkedList:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

def add_tail_node(self, val: int):
    node = self.head
    while True:
        if node.next is None:
            node.next = Node(val)
            break
        node = node.next

class Node:
def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
    self.next = None
sample_list = LinkedList
sample_list.head = Node("a")
sample_list.add_tail_node(sample_list, "b")
```

Comment: `sample_list = LinkedList` should be `sample_list = LinkedList()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning class reference to a variable here

```
sample_list = LinkedList
```

When you need to call a class, so it creates a instance

```
sample_list = LinkedList()
```

###### For better undersanding

When you are calling

```
sample_list.head = Node("a")
```

You are actualy assigning `head` to a class itself

And when you are calling object method using class, you need to provide class object instance variable first (`self` value), which is suited automatically when calling method from instance object

```
sample_list.add_tail_node(sample_list, "b")
```

This will actually process `add_tail_node` method on a class itself, not it's  instance